# Hide row if no image to display in HTML

Tags: html, css, hide

I have a HTML file that should display image for an item. The source of the image is stored as a link in a database and is marked by the placeholder <%IMAGE%> in the html file. There are some items that doesn't have any images. So, I want to hide the row instead of display a large empty cell.

```
//<%IMAGE%> = placeholder for image link

<tr style = "empty-cells:hide;">
    <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">
        <img src="<%IMAGE%>" style="width:100%"></img>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Example of the placeholder <%IMAGE%>

```
<%IMAGE%> = "http://mywebsite.com/image/icon-jobs.png"
```

I have tried empty-cells:hide but it doesn't work.

Comment: what is an example value of your place holder?

Comment: If there is no image, will only the source be empty or no img tag?

Comment: Put the css property `empty-cells` on the table, not in the row

Comment: @user1149244 I just updated the question with an example of the img src. It's usually a link.

Comment: @AndreasFurster If there are no data in the database, it should return empty string. I tried both on the table and row. It didn't work for both.

Comment: @Cryssie Is it not possible to check if there is a source and than don't set the `td`?

Comment: @AndreasFurster - the part that does the processing of data is done by the system and I have no access to that. It only return empty string or link at this point. If I have access to it, I would control it so it returns entire <td> .. </td> instead of just empty string or link.

Comment: Ok, so what you need to do is do a checking. If there is a value, display the image if none, then do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/c0wfe7wv/22/)

---

Key Code:

```
function imgError(image) {
    $(image).parent('div.column').css('display','none');
}
```

Comment: There is no need for any Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that source image is stored in Database all you have to do is to check whether image source is fetched from database.

```
<?php if($image):?>
<tr style = "empty-cells:hide;">
    <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">
        <img src="<%IMAGE%>" style="width:100%"></img>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php else:?>
    <div>No images found</div>
<?php endif;?>
```